# using different font weight of the same google font in css

Tags: css, fonts

So I'm looking at this Google font called Roboto

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto

It comes in different styles such as light, regular, medium, etc.

The site says to import you can do

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

and then in your style sheet you can do:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Well, thats fine, but I need a mixture of them. Such as light, and regular, not just one.

So I can do

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500');
```

and this selects them all.

But it still says in the style sheet you can do:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
```

If you do that, then it just sticks to the first one. I need one style to be 300, one to 400, one to be 500. So  how do I specify which one in the css?

I've tried doing

```
font-family: 'Roboto:300', sans-serif
```

and

```
font-family: 'Roboto 300', sans-serif
```

and 
`font-family: 'Roboto-300', sans-serif`

but none of them worked. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `font-weight` property

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

Example:

```
p.normal {
    font-weight: normal;
}

p.thick {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p.thicker {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: So are you saying I only need the 'regular'?

Comment: No. You have to import all the type of fonts that you want to use (normal, italic, bold, italic-bold...) and then you specify which one to use in the css by using the `font-weight` property. Mind that with `font-weight` you set how thin the text will be, and with `font-style` you can set it italic or normal

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you

Comment: For some reason there seems to be only 2 states. normal and bold. 900 does the same as bold. but there seems to be no difference between 300 and 400. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What i recommend is have a class that defines the font to be used
i.e after importing the google font, in your css add:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,600');

.robotoriser{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: Normal; /*  This is just so when ever you call use this class, it uses the normal font weight by default */
}

.rbt-300{ /* you can also name this rbt-light or whatever you like*/
font-weight:300;
}

.rbt-400{
font-weight:400;
}

.rbt-600{
font-weight:600;
}
```

... and so on.

Then use in html like this

```
<p class="robotoriser rbt-300" >This is light text</p>

<p class="robotoriser rbt-400" >This is medium text</p>

<p class="robotoriser rbt-600" >This is heavy text</p>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojanti/wyb6bjkn/) to a working demo

Note you can also use it in any class you have
e.g

```
.some_element{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300; /* Or any of the font weight values you included via the Google font url  */
}

<p class="some_element"> Dragons are goats that can fly :D </p>
```

Comment: Check theseYou have to make sure

Comment: @user6950100 , font-weight:300 and  font-weight:300 arent thesame as illustrated in the fiddle of my answer above.
Check these
- Check if the you added all the font weights in the Google font URL and make sure its valid
- Inspect your code to find out if another styling rule isnt overwriting the font-weight of the class or element you want to style

If you have a link we can check, that'll be great